# Oracle Apex Data Loader error ORA-06512 -- No Uploaded content found in collection CLOB_CONTEXT

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

I am using Apex Data Loader Wizard in Apex 5.1.1.00.08 I am able to use Upload file functionality to go to the Next step. But when I use Copy/Paste functionality I get ORA-01403: no data found as shown below.

```
is_internal_error: false
ora_sqlcode: 100
ora_sqlerrm: ORA-01403: no data found
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_PROCESS
component.id: 27972280362924791
component.name: Parse Uploaded Data
error_backtrace:
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_DATA_UPLOAD", line 693
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", line 1003
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", line 1208
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 2399
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050100.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS", line 191
```

Apex Debug log:

[Apex Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXHdw.png)

Note: I am able to achieve Copy/Paste functionality in Oracle Apex Sample application on the same workspace but does not work in different application.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried it on apex.oracle.com, no problems whatsoever. A few suggestions, if I may:

- pay attention to whether the first row you copy/pasted contains
  column headers or not and mark it appropriately
- use the same field separator (for example, a semi-colon) for all fields and rows you load
- check whether data you enter contains some "invisible" control characters -
  paste contents that should be loaded into a text editor (such as
  Notepad++) and choose "View - Show Symbol - Show all characters" (or
  a similar option); remove or replace them, if necessary

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The problem is it works perfectly fine in Oracle Sample Application that comes with Apex. But on the same workspace I have Custom application in which this functionality fails. The problem is with the Custom application where I am seeing this error. Looks like Apex engine is not able to store the clob in some table. But I am not sure how to debug this.

Comment: @user, try to export the whole application. It will be a SQL file. Open it in any text editor and search for 27972280362924791 (it is the component ID, listed in Debug info). Perhaps it'll reveal some additional information.

Comment: Let me check that.